# E-mail notification script

Tags: python

I've created a script for my service, and  I'm stuck to the last `elif` condition. What I want to do is if the service is down, the script should email me in 5 minutes. If the service is up, it should send me just one email telling me the service is up, and no more other notifications. How do I build the condition?

My code is like the following:

```
import subprocess
import os

stat = subprocess.call(["systemctl", "is-active", "--quiet", "my_service"])
if(stat == 0):  # if 0 (active), print "Active"
    print("My service is running well, send just one email.")
elif(stat != 0):
    print("My service is Inactive, send me the notification until the service is up")
```

Comment: You could build a csv file containing the time when certain events have happend. Then load it again and check if a mail has already been sent for example.

Comment: Use `time.sleep(300)` to wait for 5 minutes and then re-check.

Comment: using time.sleep(300) before the stat or after the stat? an example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store some state somewhere.  Something like:

```py
from time import sleep
SLEEP_MINS = 5
POLL_S = 30

while True:
    while not subprocess.call(cmd):
        print("everything running")
        sleep(60 * SLEEP_MINS)

    send_email()
    
    while subprocess.call(cmd):
        sleep(POLL_S)
```

Plenty of other ways to store the state---a flag variable, or a file (if the program shouldn't run constantly), etc.  But I prefer implicit state for short scripts like this (here the 'have emailed' state is stored by being in the loop waiting for the service to have started again).

Answer (score 0):

I think the SLEEP Mins is not working for my script:

```
import subprocess
import json
import socket
from alertmanager import AlertManager
from alertmanager import Alert
from time import sleep
SLEEP_MINS = 5
POLL_S = 30
   

instance_server = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

prom_service_down = {
    "labels": {
        "alertname": "Prometheus Service",
        "instance": instance_server,
        "severity": "Critical"
    },
    "annotations": {
        "description": "The Prometheus Service is down",
        "summary": "Check the prometheus service"
        }
    }

prom_service_up = {
    "labels": {
        "alertname": "Prometheus Service",
        "instance": instance_server,
        "severity": "Normal"
    },
    "annotations": {
        "description": "The Prometheus Service is up",
        "summary": "Nothing to do"
        }
    }



prom_alert_down = Alert.from_dict(prom_service_down)
prom_alert_up = Alert.from_dict(prom_service_up)
type(prom_alert_down)
prom_alert_down.add_label('prom_label', 'The Prometheus Service is down')

type(prom_alert_up)
prom_alert_up.add_label('prom_label', 'Prometheus Service is running')

host = 'http://localhost'
a_manager_down = AlertManager(host=host)
#a_manager_down.post_alerts(prom_alert_down)

a_manager_up = AlertManager(host=host)
#a_manager_up.post_alerts(prom_alert_up)

while True:
    while not subprocess.call(["systemctl", "is-active", "--quiet", "prometheus"]):
        print("The Prometheus service is running well")
        sleep(60 * SLEEP_MINS)
        a_manager_up.post_alerts(prom_alert_up)
        alerts_up = a_manager_up.get_alerts()
        print(json.dumps(prom_alert_up, indent=4))

    while subprocess.call(["systemctl", "is-active", "--quiet", "prometheus"]):
        print("The Prometheus service is down, please check")
        sleep(POLL_S)
        a_manager_down.post_alerts(prom_alert_down)
        alerts_down = a_manager_down.get_alerts()
        print(json.dumps(prom_alert_down, indent=4))
```

Seems the "while true" doesn't care about condition :

[image]

Is still "sending" notification to the alertmanager" :) when the prometheus service is up.

Comment: This is a different question (and answers are not for questions). Your code sends a message every loop in the first loop; your original q was just sending the "failed" msg (unless I misread).  Either use an explicit test before the while loop (`if`) or a flag variable inside the loop to send only once.